# ODI how to compare clob fields

Tags: oracle-data-integrator, scd

I'm trying to implement ODI scd km and the table has a clob field. I'm getting error in the step where it compares the clob value from the target table with the i$ temporary table.

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Any suggestions on how to get past this error

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare clobs in oracle. What you could do is to compute a hash value over the clob and the compare the hash value.